# Identify the Drink Given Other Info

Tags: logical-deduction, word-property

There is a smooth dance, a ball sport, a country's capital, a month, and a drink.

What's the drink?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The drink is:

> Whiskey

Because the other things are:

Smooth dance:

> Foxtrot

Ball sport:

> Golf

Country's Capital:

> Lima

Month:

> November

Which are:

> All letters of the Nato phonetic alphabet, and the clues were also in alphabetical order

Comment: Everyone answers my puzzles so easily, good job!

Comment: @ThatOneNerdyBoy It wasn't that the puzzle was so easy, it was that I was thinking of doing a puzzle using the same theme so all the words were already in my head.